# Article source link for posts

Tags: plugins, posts

Is there a way to add a source link at the end of an article like [TechnoBuffalo](http://www.technobuffalo.com/2012/12/27/windows-rt-hacked-to-run-on-htc-hd2/) (scroll down to end of post) with a plugin?

If someone could find a plugin or quickly make one for me that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats what meta_boxes are for. First you need to register the metabox within the page or post with the function [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box). Then you want to get that value with [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) on the page where you want the "Source".

This goes into your functions.php file:

```
/* Define the custom box */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse_source_link' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_source_link_save' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function wpse_source_link() {

    add_meta_box(
        'source_link',
        __( 'Source-link', 'myplugin_textdomain' ), 
        'wpse_source_meta_box',
        'post',
        'side'
    );
}

/* Prints the box content */
function wpse_source_meta_box( $post ) {

  // Use nonce for verification
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );

  // The actual fields for data entry
  echo '<input type="text" id="source-link"" name="source_link" value="'. get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) .'" size="25" />';
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function wpse_source_link_save( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times

  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      return;


  // Check permissions

  if ( current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {

      update_post_meta( $post_id, '_source_link', $_POST['source_link'] );

   }
}
```

This code register the meta_box and stores the value in post_meta as "_source_link".

It will look like this:

[image]

Then you want to get the value in the post, Use get_post_meta:

```
<?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) ); ?>
```

You should read about:
[add_meta_boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box),
[update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) and
[get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will have a go with this later. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ACF](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77501/article-source-link-for-posts),

1. Create field to enter the link and then create a field to enter the link text
2. Use the code  `Source: <a href="<?php echo get_field('url_field'); ?>"><?php echo get_field('link_text'); ?></a>`