# Wordpress - source link plugin - how to modify it?

Tags: plugins, customization

I'm using a little plugin that allows me to add source link to every article. I found the code in this thread: [Article source link for posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77501/article-source-link-for-posts)

It's almost perfect, but I would like to modify it a little: first of all, I need to have one more field for link's anchor. Now there's just a "source link" field - when I paste a link here, it shows exactly the same way in post (for example: www.stackexchange.com/questions/21652pn626262pinnpznxpiqtq/.

I need an additional anchor field to be able to set a nice link's title. For example: StackOverflow (which leads to to the destinated article - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ - for example.)

It should look like that:

Anchor text: StackOverflow
Source link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

**All links need to have a nofollow attribut**e.

This is how it looks now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl7Ij.png
This is how I want it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpMoS.png

Does anyone know how can I modify it that way?

Kacper

Comment: Hi Kacper. Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Hey! Yes, I still need help with this. :) Had no luck with answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the extra (link/URL label) field like so:

1. In the `wpse_source_meta_box()` function, add the (HTML of the) extra field:

   ```
   echo '<input type="text" id="source-link-label"" name="source_link_label" value="'.
     get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link_label', true ) .'" size="25" />';
   ```

   so as you can see, the field name is `_source_link_label` as used in the `get_post_meta()` call when retrieving the field value.

   However, since there are now two fields, you may want to add a `placeholder` to the `input` fields:

   ```
     echo '<input type="text" id="source-link"" name="source_link" value="'.
       get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) .'" size="25" placeholder="URL" />';

     echo '<input type="text" id="source-link-label"" name="source_link_label" value="'.
       get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link_label', true ) .'" size="25" placeholder="Label" />';
   ```

   Or add a `<label>` before the fields:

   ```
     echo '<label for="source-link">URL:</label> ';
     echo '<input type="text" id="source-link"" name="source_link" value="'.
       get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) .'" size="25" />';

     echo '<label for="source-link-label">Label:</label> ';
     echo '<input type="text" id="source-link-label"" name="source_link_label" value="'.
       get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link_label', true ) .'" size="25" />';
   ```
2. In the `wpse_source_link_save()` function, save/update the field value like so:

   ```
   update_post_meta( $post_id, '_source_link_label', $_POST['source_link_label'] );
   ```
3. And then use the field value (or the link label) along with the link URL, like so:

   ```
   <?php
   // Show if the source link was specified.
   if ( $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) ) :
       $label = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link_label', true );
       $label = $label ? $label : $url;
   ?>
       <div class="source-link">
           Source: <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>"><?php // wrapped (for clarity)
             echo esc_html( $label ); ?></a>
       </div>
   <?php endif; // end $url ?>
   ```

   *(Part of the code was taken from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/320925/137402).)*

So the full code, without the step #3's part, would look like [this](https://pastebin.com/5b520wqt). :)

That should work, but I suggest you to use `sanitize_text_field()` when updating the fields:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_source_link', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['source_link'] ) );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_source_link_label', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['source_link_label'] ) );
```

See [this article](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/) for more details on that.

### UPDATE

You can use this code in place of what I gave in *step #3* above, to make sure the source link is only shown on the last page of a multi-page content (split using `<!--nextpage-->`) — the link (if set) would always be shown on the first page if the content is not set to multi-page:

```
<?php
global $post, $pages, $page;

$total = count( $pages );
// Show if there's only one page, or that we're on the last page.
if ( $total < 2 || $page === $total ) :
    // Show if the source link was specified.
    if ( $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) ) :
        $label = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link_label', true );
        $label = $label ? $label : $url;
    ?>
        <div class="source-link">
            Source: <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>"><?php
              echo esc_html( $label ); ?></a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; // end $url
endif; // end last page check
?>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!!! :) There's one more thing - all source links need to have nofollow attribute. What should I do in order to achieve it? :-)

Comment: You can do it like so: `<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>" rel="nofollow">`

Comment: I mean, in step #3, just add the `rel` attribute to the `<a>` tag. But I guess you've figured it out. ;) And you can add any other (valid) attributes to that tag.

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you!

Might I ask you one more question? 

Here's how the metabox looks like now: https://i.imgur.com/RhuZTrg.png - can we move the label above the text field? It looks bad if I change the label name to something in my language - https://i.imgur.com/lFHuh6t.png

EDIT: Yeah, I figured it you - I'm not that bad :)

Comment: Yes, we can. But you could also just add a `<br>` (line break) after the URL field: `echo '<input type="text" id="source-link"" name="source_link" value="'. get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) .'" size="25" placeholder="URL" /><br>';` RE the EDIT: Ok, that's awesome! :)

Comment: Thank you :)

Btw. I just checked if the source link shows up only  on the last page of a post splitted in pages. Unfortunately, it shows up on all pages. You said that you took part of the code from here (which was responsible for fixing this) - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320908/post-source-link-plugin-small-modification/320925#320925 - can we correct this?

Comment: Yep, sure we can. :) Please check the updated answer. And (now that you've got the privilege), would you upvote my answer...? ;)

Comment: Of course! Everything's fixed. Thank you so much! :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome! :) (PS: I edited the answer, but just some text addition.)

Comment: Ouh, okay, I see :) Thank you once again. Have a good night (or day)! :-)

Comment: Same to you, and happy coding! :)