# Post source link plugin - small modification

Tags: plugins, php, functions, customization

I'm using a little plugin that allows me to add source link to every article. I found the code in this thread: [Article source link for posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77501/article-source-link-for-posts)

It's almost perfect, but I need to make 2 little modifications:

1. When there's no source link, the word "Source:" is still showing up (here's how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOt5T.png), but I need to get rid of it if no source link is added. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?
2. Source link shows on every page of a post. I have some posts splitted into multiple pages, but the link still shows on each one of them. I need to change this - the link has to show up only on the last page of a splitted post. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Here's the code I'm using (pasted in functions.php): [Article source link for posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77501/article-source-link-for-posts) - the first one

And here's what I have in my single.php (single post):

```
<div class="source-link">Source: <?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) ); ?></div>
```

Thanks in advance. Im desperate for help.

Kacper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so: **(use this in place of the one in the question)**

```
<?php
global $post, $pages, $page;

$total = count( $pages );
// Show if there's only one page, or that we're on the last page.
if ( $total < 2 || $page === $total ) :
    // Show if the source link was specified.
    if ( $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) ) :
    ?>
        <div class="source-link">
            Source: <?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; // end $url
endif; // end last page check
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you just tell me where should I paste it? I don't wanna to break the site (I'm a beginner)

Comment: Hi. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: You're welcome, and I appreciate it if you could accept the answer. :)

Comment: You're very welcome! ;)